# Link libsndfile source code with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, libsndfile

I just cloned [libsndfile](https://github.com/erikd/libsndfile) and created program.c file with the following contents:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sndfile.h>
main() {
    printf("hello world");
}
```

My goal is to get this file to compile using gcc (if indeed sndfile.h is the right header to include), however, I am not competent with c code nor the gcc compiler.

So far I've been referencing the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.1.0/gcc.pdf) and the [libsndfile FAQ](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/FAQ.html) and haven't been able to come up with a solution. I'm not sure if *I even have a 'library' yet to feed the gcc -l option*. Do I need to go through some sort of build process with the libsndfile source code first or can I 'link' to .c files?

So far, with program.c and the libsndfile clone directory in the same directory, I've tried the following:

```
gcc 'pkg-config --cflags libsndfile' program.c -o hello
gcc 'pkg-config --cflags ./libsndfile/sndfile.pc.in' program.c -o hello
```

I'm coding on my raspberry pi model B and did not install libsndfile, so, nothing is on my path... maybe I should rename sndfile.pc.in to sndfile.pc and somehow put it on my path? (not a linux guru either!)

If there are some resources you think I should study please comment! I'm perfectly willing to accept answers that simply push me enough to figure things out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a package `libsndfile-dev` or `libsndfile1-dev` for your OS? Using it might be easier than compiling it yourself, unless you need a specific version of it. This package should contain a pkg-config file `sndfile.pc` with the correct settings that you could use.

Comment: There's instructions on how to "setup a build environment for debian", which includes `sudo apt install autoconf autogen automake build-essential libasound2-dev \
    libflac-dev libogg-dev libtool libvorbis-dev pkg-config python` that I should probably try

Comment: Seems like I need to learn quite a bit more about the GNU Build System

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have `gcc` installed:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Then, install `libsndfile1-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libsndfile1-dev
```

I slightly fixed you code to avoid some warnings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sndfile.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Now you can compile:

```
gcc -o hello program.c
```

Execution:

```
bebs@rasp:~$ ./hello                                     
hello world                                                                              
bebs@rasp:~$
```

Comment: getting the right packagenames is sometimes a pita especially if they all seem to have a very similar name and its not really clear which one you need. fixed a completly different issue I had

Answer (score 1):

A small supplement of @alpereira7's answer.
It would cause linking failure without its lib. `gcc -lsndfile -o hello program.c` should be a 100% solution.